# Kinetic equation material derivative

Tags: statistical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I am reading through Raizer's Gas Discharge Physics textbook, and I cannot figure out a bit of the math he used to get from one stage to the next. The subject is the how the distribution function changes as a result of collisions. Here is an excerpt of the section I am struggling with.

[image: Raiser Excerpt 1]

And for context, here is Figure 5.1 as referenced and some of the description on how the velocity term is expressed in spherical coordinates with the Electric field being the reference axis for the coordinate system.

[image: Raizer Excerpt 2]

I cannot for the life of me, figure out how he got from equation 5.7 to 5.8. Specifically, I don't understand where the $\frac{df}{d(cos\theta)}$ term is coming from. As best I understand it the $\frac{e\boldsymbol{E}}{m}\bullet\nabla$ should be a scalar differential operator given that f is simply a scalar field in phase space. So if I convert equation given for $grad_v$ into Cartesian coordinates and perform the inner product math on that term, I end up with only a $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ term. I know there has to be some nuance here that I am missing that allows that term to arise. Can someone please help me understand the mathematical steps taken to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the coordinate system in Fig 5.1, the electric field can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E} = E\left(\cos \vartheta \hat{e}_v - \sin \vartheta \hat{e}_\vartheta \right).
\end{equation}
Then, computing the dot product with the gradient, we have:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E} \cdot \text{grad}_vf = E\left( \cos\vartheta \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} - \frac{\sin \vartheta}{v} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vartheta} \right).
\end{equation}
By the chain rule, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vartheta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \cos\vartheta} \frac{\partial \cos \vartheta}{\partial \vartheta} = -\sin\vartheta\frac{\partial f}{\partial \cos\vartheta}.
\end{equation}
By substituting this into the above, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E} \cdot \text{grad}_vf = E\left( \cos\vartheta \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} + \frac{\sin^2 \vartheta}{v} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \cos\vartheta} \right),
\end{equation}
which is the form of Eq (5.8).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have an additional clarifying question on the first line here though. Is that $\theta$ in reference to the vector v? Or is it a separate $\theta$ value from which E is measured with respect to what would be a common axis for the coordinate system? I.e. in the figure in the text, $\theta$ is zero so you get that E really only has an $\hat e_v$ component, but what you have written is more broadly true? If it's the latter shouldn't the different $\theta$ values be marked to indicate their uniqueness? If it's the former, aren't we then double referencing $\theta$?

Comment: By which I mean, the vector v is defined by the angle $\theta$ it makes with respect to the vector E, and the gradient references that value. If we say E is now defined by the angle it makes with respect to v, then is the definition of the gradient of v still valid? Shouldn't the values dependent upon the $\theta$ and $\phi$ now drop to zero?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but the first line that I wrote comes from the fact that $\mathbf{E}$ was chosen to be in the $z$-direction. In the figure, this means that it has both a $\hat{e}_v$ and $\hat{e}_\vartheta$ component, but not a $\hat{e}_\varphi$ component. You can see, for instance, wiki for how the coordinate systems are related (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). The expression for $\text{grad}_v$ is always valid, the subscript $v$ just means it's referring to velocity, but it is the gradient in spherical coordinates regardless.

Comment: *facepalm* thank you so much. I realize now where my misunderstanding has been coming from. I completely forgot the nuance in spherical coordinates that the unit vectors are set by the point in space, in this case the vector V. And not setup where the unit vector for the magnitude is along the polar axis. Thank you again for the great answer.